# How do I get the name of the WAR file?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

How can a class get the name of the WAR file that is using it?

This is for diagnostic purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in servlet

```
String warName = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("/")).getName();
```

you can use this.

Comment: On JBoss AS7, in a war called `fu.war`, this evaluates to `fu.war-a714101a57c33ed9`. In some servlet containers, this may well work, but it's evidently not required to by the spec.

Comment: This will throw `NullPointerException` when the container is configured to expand WAR in memory instead of in disk.

Comment: Not? How do you know about the OP's specific server configuration? He didn't tell anything about it in the question.

Comment: @BalusC you're right it throws a 'NullPointerException', have an idea on how doing that if so?

Answer (score 8):

`ServletContext.getContextPath()`

This returns the context path of the application (or "" for the root context). Within a servlet container, no two applications will ever have the same value for this.

**EDIT:**

And for those who don't know what the context path is: it's the URI prefix for the application. In most cases, it defaults to the name of the war file, unless you configure it explicitly. So if you have foo.war, then you'll access it at `http://localhost:8080/foo/`, and the above function will return "/foo".