# How to get the path of web application's war file?

Tags: java, tomcat

I need to get the full file path of war file using just the war file name as input. I mean, the return value should be like C:/PFiles/project/tomcat/sender/sender.war

I have tried to get the path using the following, but it doesn't give me the correct path.

```
File file = new File("sender.war");
String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
```

How to find the correct path?

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727507/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-the-war-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the system property of tomcat.
`String tomcatHome = System.getProperty( "catalina.base" );`

This will give you the home directory from there you can add `tomcatHome+"webapps/yourwar"`.